# Excluding results from Google Places API

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I'm wondering if there's any way to exclude certain results from a query to the Google Places API.

I'd like to do it in two ways if possible, but if someone can help me make either one work, that would be extremely helpful (or the answer may be that it's just not possible, and if that's the case, so be it)

- Select a place type, but exclude another. IE I want to search for "beauty salons" but I want to filter out results that are also type "hair care"
- Exclude certain specific places, so if I search for grocery stores, but I don't like Kroger, I want to search for "grocery stores not named Kroger"

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way to do it in Places API.

There is a feature request in public issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35822993

However, it looks like Google didn't set a high priority on this task. The only option for us is to star the public issue and let Google know that we are interested in this feature.